# Linked List implementation to store command history in my shell

Tags: c, shell, linked-list

I am working on a basic unix shell, and one of the features I would like to add is a 'history' command which spits out all of the commands the user has tried during that session. My research suggests that the best way to implement this is using a Linked List.

Here is my implementation, regardless of the commands I enter, it only stores the "history" command. I only included what I thought was necessary in the main shell program.

Here is output

```
//output
mish> echo Hello World
Hello World
mish> date
Sat Dec 14 16:35:31 EST 2013
mish> history
============ Command History ============
[1] history
[2] history
[3] history
=========================================
mish>
```

Here is main shell

```
//main.c
List *historyList = malloc (sizeof(List));
//get command
addHistory(historyList, command);

//do other shell stuff (parsing, etc.)
if (userInput is "history)
    printHistory;
```

Here is history.c

```
//history.c
typedef struct History{
    char *command;
    struct History *next;
}History;

typedef struct List{
    unsigned int count;
    History *top;
}List;

void  addHistory(List *list, char *cmd){
    History *h = (History*) malloc(sizeof(History));
    h->command = cmd;

    if (isHistoryEmpty(list)){
        h->next = NULL;
        list->top = h;
    }
    else{
        h->next = list->top;
        list->top =  h;
    }
    list->count++;
}

bool isHistoryEmpty(List *list){
    if (list->count == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void clearHistory(List *list){
    while (!isHistoryEmpty(list)){
        History *temp = list->top;
        list->count--;
        list->top = list->top->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    free(list);
}

void printHistory(List *list){
    int i = 1;
    printf("Command History\n"); 
    while (!list->top == NULL){ //this line causes a warning on compilation (comparison between pointer and integer)
        History *temp = list->top;
        printf("[%d] %s \n", i, temp->command);
        list->top = list->top->next;
        i++;
    }
}                                                           19,2-5        Top
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't make a copy of `command`, so all your history items share the `command` buffer. When the user types a command it is read into the sole buffer and all the history items 'change' to the latest command.

```
History *h = (History*) malloc(sizeof(History));
h->command = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(cmd) + 1));
strcpy(h->command, cmd);
```

The copy will have to be freed when the list is cleared.

Some more bugs:

- `!` has higher precedence than `==`, so either use `!=` or use brackets: `!(list->top == NULL)`
- When iterating through the list you must not modify `list->top`. Instead, move the declaration and initialization of `temp` to outside the loop and use `temp` instead of `list->top` thereafter.

Comment: Tom, thanks, your fix solved that issue. I've discovered another bug with my printHistory function, it destroys the history once it's been printed!

Comment: Yep, I have added the following in my clearHistory function: free(temp->command);